# Copy child nodes from specific parent node and change value of child node

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy the every node expect the first node  and change value of child node  based on value in source XML.

I am able to copy node  and  and change value of tag  based on source value. But I am not able to copy rest of nodes like App, header, data, sender...

Source XML:

```
<root>
    <App>
        <header>
            <sender>
                <name>PC1</name>
            </sender>
        </header>
        <data>
            <A></A>
            <B></B>
            <C></C>
        </data>
    </App>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/App/header/sender" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/App/header/sender">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Desktop'" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/App/header/sender/name">
    <xsl:element name="name">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(string(.))">
                <xsl:value-of select="'Desktop'" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Desktop-',.)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Current output:

```
<root>
   <name>Desktop-PC1</name>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<App>
    <header>
        <sender>
            <!-- if tag <name> has some value -> add prefix "Desktop-" -->
            <name>Desktop-PC1</name>

            <!-- if tag <name> has empty value or whole tag missing  -> add default value "Desktop" 
            <name>Desktop</name>
            --> 
        </sender>
    </header>
    <data>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
    </data>
</App>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such tasks I would always start with the identity transformation template and then match on that particular element (as long as it is available) or on the parent if the child is not available:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="default" select="'Desktop'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="App/header/sender/name[normalize-space()]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="$default"/>-<xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="App/header/sender/name[not(normalize-space())]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="$default"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="App/header/sender[not(name)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="$default"/>
          </name>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwrB/0, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwrB/1, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwrB/2

The other transformation task to solely output the `App` child of the `root` element is then solved y adding a template for that `root` that simply uses `apply-templates`

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwrB/3

Comment: Great work @MartinHonnen. But how can I can I get the output without the tag <root>? So in output will be a "new root" tag <App>?

Comment: @JakubOškera, see the edit, if you have the approach starting with the identity transformation template it is then easy to add a template doing another transformation step on the `root`, in this case to "strip" it or replace it with its children you simply use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.